# How to create Postgres to Postgres foreign data table

Tags: postgresql

I need to access tables in a remote Postgres database. I spent a couple hours reading through docs last night, and this is what I've come up with.

```
-- surely this thing is already written somewhere?
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_fdw_handler()
    RETURNS fdw_handler
    AS '?????' LANGUAGE C STRICT;

-- surely this thing is already written somewhere?
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_fdw_validator(text[], oid)
    RETURNS void
    AS '????' LANGUAGE C STRICT;

CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER pgsql
    HANDLER pgsql_fdw_handler
    VALIDATOR pgsql_fdw_validator;

CREATE SERVER products_remote FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER pgsql OPTIONS
    (host 'localhost', dbname 'product_db', port '1234');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
    SERVER products_remote;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE products (
  name text,
  id integer
) SERVER products_remote;

select * from products;
```

I can't figure out what to do for the handler and validator functions, do they exist somewhere? Do I need to write them myself? (what would that look like?) And would appreciate a validation of the overall approach.

I did find [this](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/action/patch_view?id=667) contrib module, but it's apparently incomplete.

Comment: The dblink module is better suited for that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. If you make it a real answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Or I can just answer myself if that's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the [pgsql_fdw code](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=565635). I could not find a tarball so you are stuck with a git clone.  To get it:

```
git clone git://interdbconnect.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/interdbconnect/interdbconnect
cd interdbconnect/pgsql_fdw
make USE_PGXS=1
make USE_PGXS=1 install;
```

Then log into pgsql

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgsql_fdw;

create foreign data wrapper postgresql  handler pgsql_fdw_handler;
create server lsmb foreign data wrapper postgresql options (host 'localhost', dbname  'mtech_test', port '5432');
create user mapping for current_user server lsmb;
create foreign table defaults (setting_key text, value text) server lsmb;
select * from defaults;
```

Then this works for me.

I don't know whether pgsql_fdw was included in contrib in 9.2.

Comment: Is this answer still accurate?  I think FDW has shipped with POSTGRES since 9.3, but it still asks for a handler function, and the documentation is opaque